# How to organize the code if I want to initialize database before each tests?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine

I'm new to jasmine, and I want to write some tests for mongodb operations.

Suppose I have several `.spec.js` files under directory `spec`, and all the tests within them should drop the testing database and inserting some testing data.

How should I organize the code? Shall I define an `init()` method somewhere, and call it from all other tests? Or is there any better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your `describe` you can call `beforeEach` and `afterEach` as usual with test frameworks. This is the right place to do setting up and tearing down of test prerequisites.

For example:

```
describe('My Module', function () {
  beforeEach(function () {
    ...
  });

  afterEach(function () {
    ...
  });

  it('...', function () { ... });

});
```

In any case though best practice would be to not actually do the db operations: Presumably you use some library that is already tested. It is going to save you a lot of hassle if you **mock** your db layer. You can do this effectively with jasmine by using [spies](http://github.com/pivotal/jasmine/wiki/Spies).

For example let's assume your db layer has a `get(id)` function that returns some json. You could be doing:

```
it('can access the db', function () {
  var spy = spyOn(db, 'get').andCallFake(function (id) {
    expect(id).toEqual('foo');
    return {title: 'Foo Bar'};
  });

  // Something here does stuff that would result to a call to db.get
  var res = db_calling_function('foo');
  expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
  expect(res).toEqual({title: 'Foo Bar'});
});
```

Comment: What if there are many test files? Do I have to write the `initdb` function in an extra file, and let these test files to `require` it, and invoke it in `beforeEach`?

Comment: I'm testing the model layer, that I should use real database to test against, right?

Comment: Concerning the many tests, you can put the beforeEach an an outer `describe`, it will run for all the inner ones too.

Comment: With regards to the real db, honestly I think no. It is better to not depend on having a real db accessible, makes your setup easier and your tests faster. In addition, your db API is surely tested independently. Of course, that should not stop you from having additional functional/integration tests that make sure the setup as a whole works.

Comment: Add to the above that you *are* really mode flexible with mocks than with the real thing. You can simulate for instance fail conditions in an easier way.

Comment: I will use mocks in other layers than model layer. But for model layer, for example, I want to test if the method `User.save()`, I have to use the real db, right?

Comment: Not really. What you need to make sure is that it calls the db API with the right parameters. The fact that this is persisted to mongodb should be guaranteed by the tests of your API. If you are using Backbone for example, you only need to know that `sync` was called with a `save`. You don't need to have the ajax call persisting it... That would be jQuery's job.